# Angularjs inside MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, razor

i am very new to angular and have been doing some basic stuff.

I am trying to convert some view to use angular and i am stuck

can someone with help how i would do the following using angular

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Home",new { propertyID=item.RentalID,PropertyType="Rentals" })"><img data-original="img/property/pic (2).jpg" alt="@item.Description" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = item.RentalID })" class="img-hover"></a>
```

i want to repleace the "item" with a data repeater {{i.Item}} for example

I've tried this but it wont work

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Details","Home",new { propertyID={{i.RentalID}},PropertyType="Rentals" })"><img data-original="img/property/pic (2).jpg" alt="{{i.Description}}" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home", new { id = {{i.RentalID }}})" class="img-hover"></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the `@Url.Action` is rendered on the server whereas the angular stuff is done later, on the client.

You could however try this:

```
<a ng-href="@Url.Action("Details","Home",new { PropertyType="Rentals" })&propertyID={{i.RentalID}}"><img data-original="img/property/pic (2).jpg" alt="{{i.Description}}" ng-src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home")?id={{i.RentalID}}" class="img-hover"></a>
```

Please note that I used [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) and [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) since we are now using dynamic properties in the URL:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in an href attribute will make the
>   link go to the wrong URL if the user clicks it before Angular has a
>   chance to replace the {{hash}} markup with its value. Until Angular
>   replaces the markup the link will be broken and will most likely
>   return a 404 error. The ngHref directive solves this problem.

Comment: Thanks, How do i do this in angular:   @{Html.RenderAction("getCityByName1", "Home", new {id = item.CityID});}